# How do you automate a Visual Studio build?

Tags: visual-studio, build-automation

How do you turn a Visual Studio build that you'd perform in the IDE into a script that you can run from the command line?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

With VS2008 you can do this:

```
devenv solution.sln /build configuration
```

Comment: This way always seems the easiest.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7(v=VS.90).aspx works with 2003,2005 and 2010 too but they recommend using msbuild instead with 2010

Answer (score 30):

```
\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[YOUR .NET VERSION]\msbuild.exe
```

Lots of command line parameters, but the simplest is just:

```
msbuild.exe yoursln.sln
```

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way: navigate to the directory containing the solution or project file, and run `msbuild` (assuming you have Visual Studio 2005 or newer).

More flexible ways:

- Read up on [the MSBuild
  reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx). There are tons of
  customization, especially once
  you've installed the [MSBuild Community Tasks Project](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks).
- Use [NAnt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAnt). It has existed
  for longer than MSBuild and has more
  community support, but requires you
  to start a project file from
  scratch, rather than extending the
  existing, Visual Studio-created one.

Answer (score 4):

**[NAnt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAnt)** and **[MSBuild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild)** are the most popular tools to automate your build in [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework), and you can find a discussion on there of the pros/cons of each in the Stack Overflow question *[Best .NET build tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16550)*.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the script I'm using to completely automate the command line build of x86 AND x64 configurations for the same solution through batch scripts.

This is based on DevEnv.exe as it works if you have a Setup project in your build (msbuild doesn't support building Setup projects).

I'm assuming your setup is 32bit Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2010 setup using the x86 native compiler and x64 cross compiler.
If you're running 64bit windows you may need to change *x86_amd64* to *amd64* in the batch script depending on your setup.
This is assuming Visual Studio is installed in *Program Files* and your solution is located in *D:\MySoln*

Create a file called *buildall.bat* and add this to it:

```
D:
cd "D:\MySoln"

if "%1" == "" goto all
if %1 == x86 goto x86
if %1 == x64 goto x64

:x86
%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86 < crosscompilex86.bat
goto eof

:x64
%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86_amd64 < crosscompilex64.bat
goto eof

:all
%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86 < crosscompilex86.bat
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 goto eof
%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86_amd64 < crosscompilex64.bat
goto eof

:eof
pause
```

Now create 2 more batch scripts:

*crosscompilex86.bat* to build the Release version of a x86 build and include this

```
devenv MySoln.sln /clean "Release|x86"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
devenv MySoln.sln /rebuild "Release|x86"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```

*crosscompilex64.bat* to build the Release version of the x64 build and include this

```
devenv MySoln.sln /clean "Release|x64"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
devenv MySoln.sln /rebuild "Release|x64"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Now place all 3 batch files along in your solution folder along with MySoln.sln.
You can build both x86 and x64 Release versions by creating a Shortcut on your desktop which run the following commands:

- Build All -> *D:\MySoln\buildall.bat*
- Build x86 Release Only -> *D:\MySoln\buildall.bat x86*
- Build x64 Release Only -> *D:\MySoln\buildall.bat x64*

If you're using another configuration like AnyCPU etc you would need to customize the above scripts accordingly.

Comment: Huh, I don't think I have seen anyone pipe a batch file into cmd.exe before. That's actually pretty clever.

Answer (score 3):

Look into  build tool [NAnt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAnt) or [MSBuild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild). I believe MSBuild is the build tool for Visual Studio 2005 and later. I am, however, a fan of NAnt...

Comment: NAnt is just a wrapper for MSBuild (hence the name of the build task is `<msbuild>`) but NAnt is cool because it lets you do other things out of the box easier than if you were to do them with custom msbuild tasks.

Answer (score 2):

As of [Visual Studio 2005](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2005), all of the project files (at least for .NET based projects) are actual [MSBuild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild) files, so you can call MSBuild on the command line and pass it the project file.

The bottom line is that you need to use a "build scripting language" like [NAnt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAnt) or MSBuild (there are others, but these are the mainstream ones right now) if you want to have any real control over your build process.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at UppercuT. It has a lot of bang for your buck and it does what you are looking for and much more.

UppercuT uses NAnt to build and it is the insanely easy to use Build Framework.

Automated Builds as easy as (1) solution name, (2) source control path, (3) company name for most projects!

[http://projectuppercut.org/](http://projectuppercut.org)

Some good explanations here: [UppercuT](http://ferventcoder.com/category/uppercut.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my batch file using **msbuild** for VS **2010** Debug configuration:

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe" 
iTegra.Web.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /clp:Summary /nologo
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this for a C++ project in Visual Studio **2003** so I don't know how relevant this is to later version of visual studio:

In the directory where your executable is created there will be a `BuildLog.htm` file. Open that file in your browser and then for each section such as:

```
Creating temporary file "c:\some\path\RSP00003C.rsp" with contents
[
/D "WIN32" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "STRICT" /D "NDEBUG" ..... (lots of other switches)
.\Project.cpp
.\Another.cpp
.\AndAnother.cpp
".\And Yet Another.cpp"
]
Creating command line "cl.exe @c:\some\path\RSP00003C.rsp /nologo"
```

create a .rsp file with the content between the square brackets (but not including the square brackets) and call it whatever you like. I seem to remember having problems with absolute paths so you may have to make sure all the paths are relative.

Then in your build script add the command line from the `BuildLog.htm` file but with your .rsp filename:

```
cl.exe @autobuild01.rsp /nologo
```

(note there will also be a link.exe section as well as cl.exe)

Answer (score -1):

A more simple way is to change VS 2015 Projects & Solutions configuration:
Go to the Tools tab -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run -> On Run, when projects are out of date (choose Always build). VOILA!

Now your IDE will automatically build your project when you run (F5) it. Hope this helps, any feedback are welcome.