# VS solution to makefile

Tags: visual-studio-2010, makefile

is there a tool to generate a makefile out of a visual studio Solution?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580/how-do-you-automate-a-visual-studio-build

Comment: Why: because we want to build the project using the GCC compiler, but the build-settings are quite complex.

Comment: Well, there exist better tools than make out there, IMO. What language are you using? I would capture the detailed output of a build under every configuration, and then reverse-engineer that into non-MSFT build setup.

Comment: I don't think you can use GCC because you need the MSIL.

Comment: I am  using c++ and want wo use the gcc compiler just at certain moments to get better error-descriptions. Finally it has to be build with MS-VS

Comment: So you just need a "compile everything" makefile with no dependency checking? Should not be to hard to roll out your own, just list every cpp file for compilation and call GCC with the appropriate options.

Answer (score 1):

Code::Blocks has an option to import Visual Studio project files. It also uses a `make` system. So you could import your project into C::B, then steal the makefile. Not sure how well that would work for you.