# How to trigger a release build after a debug build in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, release-builds, debug-build

Since I need to launch a release build after every debug build I'd like to have it scripted. Is there any way in VS2015 to force a release build after a debug one?

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34063/4610605 and add this to your `PostBuild-Events` in the section `BuildEvents` of your project properties.